# Password asterisk feedback mysteriously enabled

Tags: 16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my machine and a while back something strange happened. All of a sudden I started getting password visual feedback (`*`) when entering the password for commands run with `sudo`.

I've checked the `/etc/sudoers` file and there is no `pwfeedback` entry for the defaults.

How can I determine why visual feedback is enabled and from where?

Comment: What about other files in `/etc/sudoers.d`? What does `sudo -l` report?

Comment: @muru Tep, that was it. The `pwfeedback` was being set from  a file in `/etc/sudoers.d`. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check into `/etc/sudoers` and `/etc/sudoers.tmp` and `/etc/sudoers.d`.

Make sure the line

```
Defaults        pwfeedback
```

is deleted.

If it is along like this

```
Defaults        env_reset,pwfeedback
```

change it into

```
Defaults        env_reset
```

Comment: `/etc/sudoers.tmp`?

Comment: Sometimes sudoers files are saved as sudoers.temp, so better take precaution and change even the temp files, even if it gets loaded in system it will not affect

Comment: sorry, but do you have anything to show that this file is used by sudo?

Comment: http://i66.tinypic.com/ctdsp.png
http://i68.tinypic.com/2ldzs0j.png
See this my system Ubuntu 16.04 loads /etc/sudoers.tmp files

Comment: That's because `visudo` copies `sudoers` to `sudoers.tmp` for editing. When you finish editing, `visudo` copies it back. `sudo` doesn't read `sudoers.tmp` by itself. Create a `sudoers.tmp` outside of `visudo` that differs from your `sudoers`and see for yourself.